# What algorithm can I use to find this extracted template image in this query image?

Tags: algorithm, image, matlab, image-processing, wavelet

[image]

I am trying to find the location of the extracted template image in the query image, I have tried using surf algorithm but it is not able to find it, please what other algorithm can i use to find this template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is relatively simple and straightforward, especially if you would have a clean dataset for the fingerprints.

You can use [Wavelet Transform](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/309784005_Fingerprint_Recognition_Technique_using_Wavelet_Transform) for extracting those features.

It would decompose your fingerprint images using a tree architecture and you can extract those desired parts of your images that you would be interested in.

I'm pretty sure you can find many packages on GitHub.

- [Fingerprint Recognition Project](https://matlab-recognition-code.com/matlab-fingerprint-recognition-system-full-source-code/)
- [Wavelet For Fingerprint Detection](https://github.com/beltagymohamed/Wavelet-for-fingerprint-detection-Matlab)
- [Gabor Method](https://github.com/mhaghighat/gabor)
- [Fingerprint Compression](https://github.com/matt77hias/FingerprintCompression)

If you can code in Python, [PyWavelets](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) would be also a choice, otherwise you can use MATLAB:

---

#### How to implement in MatLab:

This code is just an example of an implemented image processing algorithm in MatLab.

### [Source Code](https://github.com/anggrainini/Bioinformatic_UTS/blob/master/dwt.m)

```
%WAVELET

clear all;
clc;

data=imread('sidikjari5.jpg');
r=data(:,:,1);
g=data(:,:,2);
b=data(:,:,3);

gray=double(0.333*r+0.333*g+0.333*b)/512;

[m, n] = size(gray);

%=================== WAVELET LV 1 ===================%

mm=m/2;
nn=n/2;
for i=1:mm
    for j=1:nn
        cb1=(gray(i*2-1,j*2));
        %cb1=double(cb1);
        cb2=(gray(i*2,j*2-1));
        %cb2=double(cb2);
        ca(i,j)=sqrt(cb1^2+cb2^2);
    end
end
[m1,n1]=size(ca);

for i=1:mm
    for j=1:nn
        cb1=(gray(i*2-1,j*2-1));
        cb2=(gray(i*2,j*2-1));
        cv(i,j)=(cb1+cb2)/2;
    end
end
[m2,n2]=size(cv);

for i=1:mm
    for j=1:nn
        cb1=(gray(i*2-1,j*2-1));
        cb2=(gray(i*2-1,j*2));
        ch(i,j)=(cb1+cb2)/2;
    end
end
[m3,n3]=size(ch);

for i=1:mm
    for j=1:nn
        cb1=(gray(i*2-1,j*2-1));
        cb2=(gray(i*2,j*2));
        cd(i,j)=(cb1+cb2)/2;
    end
end
[m4,n4]=size(cd);

l1=figure;
imshow(l1);
subplot(2,2,1);
imshow(ca);
title('ca');
subplot(2,2,2);
imshow(ch);
title('ch');
subplot(2,2,3);
imshow(cv);
title('cv');
subplot(2,2,4);
imshow(cd);
title('cd');

%=================== WAVELET LV 2 ===================%

mmm=m1/2;
nnn=n1/2;
for i=1:mmm
    for j=1:nnn
        cb1=(ca(i*2-1,j*2));
        cb2=(ca(i*2,j*2-1));
        ca2(i,j)=sqrt(cb1^2+cb2^2);
    end
end
[mm1,nn1]=size(ca2);

for i=1:mmm
    for j=1:nnn
        cb1=(ca(i*2-1,j*2-1));
        cb2=(ca(i*2,j*2-1));
        cv2(i,j)=(cb1+cb2)/2;
    end
end
[mm2,nn2]=size(cv2);

for i=1:mmm
    for j=1:nnn
        cb1=(ca(i*2-1,j*2-1));
        cb2=(ca(i*2-1,j*2));
        ch2(i,j)=(cb1+cb2)/2;
    end
end
[mm3,nn3]=size(ch2);

for i=1:mmm
    for j=1:nnn
        cb1=(ca(i*2-1,j*2-1));
        cb2=(ca(i*2,j*2));
        cd2(i,j)=(cb1+cb2)/2;
    end
end
[mm4,nn4]=size(cd2);

l2=figure;
imshow(l2);
subplot(2,2,1);
imshow(ca2);
title('ca2');
subplot(2,2,2);
imshow(ch2);
title('ch2');
subplot(2,2,3);
imshow(cv2);
title('cv2');
subplot(2,2,4);
imshow(cd2);
title('cd2');

%=================== WAVELET LV 3 ===================%

mmmm=mm1/2;
nnnn=nn1/2;
for i=1:mmmm
    for j=1:nnnn
        cb1=(ca2(i*2-1,j*2));
        cb2=(ca2(i*2,j*2-1));
        ca3(i,j)=sqrt(cb1^2+cb2^2);
    end
end
[mmm1,nnn1]=size(ca3);

for i=1:mmmm
    for j=1:nnnn
        cb1=(ca2(i*2-1,j*2-1));
        cb2=(ca2(i*2,j*2-1));
        cv3(i,j)=(cb1+cb2)/2;
    end
end
[mmm2,nnn2]=size(cv3);

for i=1:mmmm
    for j=1:nnnn
        cb1=(ca2(i*2-1,j*2-1));
        cb2=(ca2(i*2-1,j*2));
        ch3(i,j)=(cb1+cb2)/2;
    end
end
[mmm3,nnn3]=size(ch3);

for i=1:mmmm
    for j=1:nnnn
        cb1=(ca2(i*2-1,j*2-1));
        cb2=(ca2(i*2,j*2));
        cd3(i,j)=(cb1+cb2)/2;
    end
end
[mmm4,nnn4]=size(cd3);

level1=[ca cv;
        ch cd;];
level2ca=[ca2 cv2;
          ch2 cd2];
level3ca=[ca3 cv3;
          ch3 cd3];

l3=figure;
imshow(l3);
subplot(2,2,1);
imshow(ca3);
title('ca3');
subplot(2,2,2);
imshow(ch3);
title('ch3');
subplot(2,2,3);
imshow(cv3);
title('cv3');
subplot(2,2,4);
imshow(cd3);
title('cd3');     
 
%=================== EKSTRAKSI CIRI WAVELET LV 3 ===================%

rerataca3 = mean2(ca3); %fitur
reratach3 = mean2(ch3); %fitur
reratacv3 = mean2(cv3); %fitur
reratacd3 = mean2(cd3); %fitur

sdevca3 = std2(ca3); %fitur
sdevch3 = std2(ch3); %fitur
sdevcv3 = std2(cv3); %fitur
sdevcd3 = std2(cd3); %fitur

varca3 = sdevca3^2; %fitur
varch3 = sdevch3^2; %fitur
varcv3 = sdevcv3^2; %fitur
varcd3 = sdevcd3^2; %fitur

x=[rerataca3  reratach3 sdevca3 sdevch3  varca3  varch3]
```

---

#### Update

I would suggest to look for an already developed package on GitHub or maybe search through similar MatLab examples, if they have. Then, apply that package or example to your images to see how it would work. In this process, you may face some problems such as preprocessing that might be required to be applied on your images before you map them with any time-frequency methods.

If not and that set a side, maybe you can start from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/image-analysis.html), if you would like to write from scratch. More specifically, [Discrete Wavelet Packet Transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet_packet_decomposition) might be an efficient algorithm for your images.

---

#### Wavelet packet seems to be designed similar to [trees](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/wpdec2.html). After you apply them to your images, you can also define and design some mathematical/statistical criteria to extract those features form your fingerprint images.

Comment: Thank you @Emma, just for clarification, will I be able to get the location of the template image in the query image? Then I am extracting more than one of these templates from the original image to find the most unique one to use for the template matching, will the number of features extracted from the templates using the wavelet approach vary so I can use the template with the most number of features as the unique one or how can I get the most unique one?

Comment: By the way I write in Matlab not Python sir

Comment: Thank you once again @Emma. I appreciate your time, I will read up on Wavelets Transform, may I just ask if it's a tricky topic to understand?

Comment: One last thing please @Emma, this code you provided, how will I use it?

Comment: Hello @Emma, i have been looking through the Wavelet Toolbox Documentation on Matlab and have come across different types of Wavelet Analysis, I'm not sure which of them pertains to my problem, can I send you a message showing what I've seen so far if you can help me pick which one i should use for this. Thanks a lot

Comment: Or let me send the link showing all the topics on matlab docs

https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/index.html

I dont know which is appropriate for my problem

Comment: Thank you @Emma, I will look through Github because i have limited time to finish this project, the wavelet transforms is a daunting topic for me, i can understand it if i have more time, but my time is limited at the moment, can i also ask if there is another approach that is rotation, scale and translation invariant for template location for templates like the one i have above? Thanks for your help, I appreciate it a lot